# Marking Maps with Schema or Using the Rich Snippet Map Feature

Tags: microdata, rich-snippets, map

I want to know if it is possible to make a Map Rich Snippet of my website, but I don't want it to be Google Maps.

[image: Google search for "mexico map", showing a map]

Haven't seen any Yahoo or Bing maps on Google SERPS.

Is it possible to make that Rich Snippet from another website? Or any other thing such as directions, images and more?

In the case it is possible. Does anyone have tried it and have any results?

Answer (score 1):

You will only see Googles maps. The SERPS get address and map data from Google Places, which has been merged into Google+ pages for business. Using a Google verified place on a verified domain in GWT, with a rel publisher keystone: you will see map, but only from Google.

So even if you define a new or non-google map using schema, it will still use the Google maps. This is to prevent you from lying or spoofing whatever map/address you want into SERPs. Its kinda tedious to authorize Google Place/domain because of this reason.

The schema map urls may be useful for other apps, directories, or search engines though, especially in the future as things like Pinterest and Twitter go rich location data.

Comment: Thanks dhaupin! Yes, that's what I thought. Google will not miss a chance to make business, allowing me to put my very own map on the SERPs Mmm.. so when Google decides to put a Rich Snippet of Google Maps on every querie related to MAP, I will be screwed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got to know of [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com) an Open Source Map project based on [OpenStreet Maps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) . I'm still understanding how to twist and twirl it so not sure it could deliver you the solution. Basically it's an open source alternative to Google Maps with a lot of programmable alternatives.